# UINavigationBar bleeding its background when PageSheet is animating

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, ios13

My application has a `UIViewController` where uses the new `.pageSheet` modal presentation style introduced on iOS 13.
This `UIViewController` has a `UINavigationBar` on the top and it's pinned, by constraints, at the top, leading and trailing.

I noticed that the background from this view bleeds in white while the `UIViewController` is animating. Take a look on this recorded GIF from a real device:

[image]

Is there anything I can do to solve this? The `UIViewController` and `UINavigationBar` were created programatically.

Maybe doing this can solve it?

```swift
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    var originalFrame = frame
    frame = originalFrame
}
```

I am using Swift 5.1 and Xcode 11.3. The iPhone is running iOS 13.1.3.

Comment: Have you tried on a real device? Might be that this is an issue present in simulators only.

Comment: Please read the post again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you set the view's layer to rasterize, this is making with the `.pageSheet` animation not draw it correctly.

The solution, **remove** the code below:

```swift
navigationBar.layer.shouldRasterize = true
navigationBar.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
```